# Click on LinkButton in Gridview: why is the Grid reloaded most of the times but not always?

Tags: c#, gridview, repeater, asplinkbutton

I´m trying to understand the annoying refreshment of the GridView/Repeater that occurs most of the times I click on a LinkButton within that element. If this is caused by the Postback, then why doesn't it happen all the times?
And if it is not caused always, do I might even get rid of it?

I usually do this to get detailed information on a cell clicked in a Grid or repeater:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="ButtonSelect" runat="server" CommandName ="Select" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("date") %>' Text='<%# Bind("TAG") %>' OnClick="GetDetails"/>
```

The data processed in the "GetDetails" method will then be displayed in some other element. There wouldn't be any need to refresh the Grid.

Is this the normal behavior for any LinkButton click in a GridView?

Martin

Comment: Could have something to do with the usage of `CommandName="Select"`. Many databuond controls have special behaviour associated with that command name. Try using a custom command name instead and see if it makes any difference. Not sure it will, but easy to test just to see what happens. Recognized command names: [see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.buttonfield.commandname(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the normal action of a server button within a gridview.  It will cause a postback.  A postback will force the Page LifeCycle.  The entire page will be recreated and Databinding may or may not occur depending on your cache options and programming.

"Fixing" that really depends what you are trying to accomplish.  If it's simply to stop the "screen flicker" due to the postback, consider using AJAX calls or `<asp:UpdatePanel>` server controls.

If you are trying to work with JS on the clientside and just wish to defer the postback until later, convert the button to a template field and replace the `<asp:LinkButton>` with a basic html control `<a href="javascript:void();" ...>`, `<button type='button'>`, `<input type='button' ...`, etc...